# How to block/unblock parts of DOM tree from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I wanna bock certain DOM subtrees from appearing in jQuery searches.

```
<div id="content">
    <p> "hello" </p>
</div>
```

```
block('#content') //hides '#content'
$('#content').length //0
unblock('#content')
$('#content').length //1
```

Basically I wanna know if there are functions like block/unblock or if we can write any?

Comment: Give it a class or attribute to label it as blocked, then everywhere you use jquery, exclude that explicitly using .not() with a callback. quite awful

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: jQuery searches? What about `querySelector` searches?

Comment: The higher level problem is that there are multiple forms present on a particular page. I wanna use jquery funtions on only one of those forms, the form which I already have. I wanna use jQuery on specifc part of page.

Comment: Then you would do either `$("#myform").find(".myinput")...` or `$("#myform .myinput")` or `var myForm = $("#myform");  var inp = $(".input", myform);`  or various other combinations.   Rather than "hide" just limit your selector / scope.

Comment: Definitely an XY problem as originally described

Answer (score -2):

You could try using the :not selector. So your search would be like this:

```
$("div:not(#content)")
```

Comment: This will only exclude the `#content` element itself, not the subtree under it

Comment: Had the OP been trying to exclude all elements under `#content`, you would write it like `$("div:not(#content *)")`